# Access raw audio/video frames from Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource

Tags: c#, .net-core, ms-media-foundation

I want to use the `Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource` in a console application without a `MediaPlayer`. Instead I'd just like to set the source as an `mp4` stream and then get the raw audio and video samples.

Below is my code which gets as far as loading the `MediaSource` but I can't see how to request the audio and video samples? There is a `MediaStreamSource` property but it's always `null`.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Media.Capture.Frames;
using Windows.Media.Core;
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;
using Windows.Media.Playback;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    [ComImport]
    [Guid("5B0D3235-4DBA-4D44-865E-8F1D0E4FD04D")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    unsafe interface IMemoryBufferByteAccess
    {
        void GetBuffer(out byte* buffer, out uint capacity);
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fs = File.Open("big_buck_bunny.mp4", FileMode.Open);

            var mp4Src = Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource.CreateFromStream(fs.AsRandomAccessStream(), "video/mp4");
            await mp4Src.OpenAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"state {mp4Src.State}, duration {mp4Src.Duration}, isopen {mp4Src.IsOpen}, has source {mp4Src.MseStreamSource}.");

            // Get access to raw audio/video samples???

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is a part of UWP Media Player API. You are not supposed to read video/audio samples using `MediaSource` because it is designated to be a wrapper over Media Foundation media sources of different kinds with uniform Media Player playback item management.

The only thing `MediaSource` is useful for is to wrap sources and schedule them for Media Player playback. Media Player is capable to access underlying Media Foundation sources behind the scene.

`MediaStreamSource` property is, in particular, `null` because this media source instance is not based on `MediaStreamSource` implementation. If you created media source supplying `MediaStreamSource` you would respectively have the property provided you access to originally supplied implementation layer. You have a source of a different type, so your non-null property is likely to be `IRandomAccessStream`.

To retrieve individual samples you need something like Media Foundation Media Sources, Media Foundation Source Reader, `Windows.Media.Capture.Frames` for cameras etc.

Comment: Ok, thx. So as you understand it I'm not going to be able to get raw frames from an mp4 file using the UWP Windows.Media.* API? Does that also mean there's probably no WinRT wrapper (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api) to do it either? I'd really like to avoid the need for my custom C++ dll.

Comment: Source Reader API works out for a UWP app why wouldn't you use it? You can use it with C++, WRL, C++/CX code or C++/WinRT. This `Windows.Media.` story is layered over normal Media Foundation and is not much developer friendly. It is not something really good for getting individual frames.

Comment: By "Source Reader API" do you mean the Win32 Media Foundation API? If so yes it works but to use it with a .net core app it requires distributing a C++ dll. And when developing a nuget library that means building/testing with x86, x64 (and now ARM64). And also typically co-ordinating/versioning C++ runtime somehow. It's preferable to rely on .net core libraries that are already installed.

Comment: You wrote that you are developing custom C++ DLL, so I assume you will have to build one for every platform anyway. Yes it's Win32 Media Foundation API, but it's Windows core you don't need to redistribute anything for it as far as I can understand.

Comment: Ok, thx again, so the answer is "No" to the UWP/WinRT angle for sampling files. It's a shame as the UWP Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture works perfectly for sampling webcams. I want to remove the need for my existing C++ dll (which does use IMFMediaSource) not develop one. I'll explore the PInvoke approach instead.